# Translate several batch script commands into python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, translate

I have a bit trouble here with translating several of mine commands into python, I am also using 3rd party software and it's own CLI commands together with batch, my batch code that goes through file and takes all lines from that file which are some paths and includes them on needed location inside of a 3rd party sw:

```
FOR /F %%i in (C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\File.d) ^
DO tessycmd add-include-dir %%i
```

I am trying to translate this in python, so far my code looks like:

```
os.system ('FOR /F %%i in (C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\File.d')+ '^'
                    result = os.system('DO tessycmd add-include-dir %%i')
```

My code does not work and all I get are errors like:

***"%%i was unexpected at this time" and
"DO is not recognized as internal or external command."***

Any idea or suggestion if I should maybe have a different approach?
Thanks!

Comment: You are executing a command line, so don't use batch syntax. On command line, replace each `%%i` with just `%i`.

Comment: Oh - and `^` as "Command Line Continuation" does not work this way. You happened to split the line and executed two `cmd` processes with half a command each.

Comment: I don't know phyton, but based on your code examples this should work: `result = os.system ('FOR /F %i in (C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\File.d) DO tessycmd add-include-dir %i') ` (probably you have to give it the full path to `tessycmd`)

Comment: Thanks man! Replacing %%i with %i is such a good hint I missed it totally.. I am still getting some errors but not same ones, there is progress!

Comment: I cannot believe that python is incapable of reading each line of a file, without having to ask internal cmd.exe commands to do it instead.

Comment: Python itself is capable, problem is that I have to do it through cli commands

Comment: @John, python runs CLI, pythonw runs GUI. You do not need to ask cmd.exe to read the file, python can open it, readline(s) it, perform a command using it, and then close it.

Comment: [read text file in phyton line by line](https://pythonexamples.org/python-read-text-file/#5)

Comment: I agree with you, thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have managed to get to the solution by:

```
  result = os.system ('FOR /F %i in (C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\File.d) DO tessycmd add-include-dir %i')
```

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have pointed out, pushing all the processing to the shell kind of defeats the purpose of using Python in the first place. You could instead do something like this:

```py
with open('C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\File.d') as file:
    for line in file:
        os.system(f'tessycmd add-include-dir {line}')
```

Comment: this can work also, I agree, thanks!